# What is the classification for a brother/sister in a fraternal religious order?

Tags: single-word-requests, class-based-usage

I was wondering what word is used to describe the classification of either a brother or sister within a fraternal religious order?

For example, *gender* classifies male or female. I think *kinship* could be used to classify the relationship of siblings (i.e. brother or sister) in family setting... Although it does cast a bit of wider net allowing for fathers, mothers, etc.

The closest thing I could find seems to be *membership*, which seems to be the right choice within a trade union or a guild. This may be the correct term in the context of a fraternal religious order, however it just doesn't seem right, especially in siutations where the organization/order doesn't have a clearly defined organizational structure or membership requirements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every religious order has their own traditions and their own traditional terms for every stage of them. _Novices, postulants, oblates, lay members, priests, brothers, nuns,_ etc, are all used in different orders for Catholics, and that's only one religion. There is no general term because there is no general "religious order". Like people, they're all different and they all talk different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the term ***fellowship*** instead. Although all dictionaries might not include this meaning, it is used in some religious environments:

> a friendly feeling that exists between people who have a shared interest or are doing something as a group:
>
> - He enjoyed the fellowship of other actors in the company.
>   Christian fellowship ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fellowship))

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fellowship) mentions it too:

> A Church or religious association. The state or relationship of being a fellow.

Also, the word ***brotherhood*** can serve in this purpose:

> A feeling of shared interests and support among men, or more generally, among all humans.
> A *brotherhood* is also ***the membership of an organization of men, or the
> organization itself***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brotherhood?topic=societies-clubs-and-organizations))

The corresponding term ***sisterhood*** also exists specifically for women:

> a society of women living a religious life ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sisterhood))

Comment: Awesome answer! Although the question got closed before I could accept it :( It seems way more natural to ask "What is your fellowship? ☐ Brother ☐ Sister" rather than using gender or membership. Thanks again!!